# Can't download playwright python properly

Tags: python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

I tried to install playwright in my laptop
I typed

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

to command prompt.

However, only the first 2 lines running without error.
I got the error message for `playwright install`:

[image: error message]

I've added playwright into path but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with `pip install`, this worked for me.

```py
python -m playwright install
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter

```
python -m playwright install
```

Below the command won't work because the path has not been set in the **environment variable**

```
 playwright install
```